# Web based project on Data Visualization with Python(Django)

Tags: django, python-3.x, data-visualization, data-analysis, plotly-dash

I want to create a web based project on Data Visualization with Python(Django), so which python library should I prefer such as dash, bookeh or similar one? Here I want to say that, "Can I able to embed my dash or bookeh based graphs in django app?"

Comment: What kind of data visualization? You mean charts and numbers?

Comment: I mean Interactive data visualization, yes it is in form of charts. @devdob

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, Is this right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a web based app, then you are better off handling this on your front end. I use packages such as [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/), [D3.js](https://d3js.org/), [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/) and [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: plotly works very well with Django.